# Getting this error in rails: `ActionView::Template::Error (code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-16))`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8

I've started getting the following error in one of my views for some reason, I don't get it in development, but only in production.

Here is a snippet of the backtrace, any ideas?

```
ActionView::Template::Error (code converter not found (UTF-8 to UTF-16)):
    19:         [title, summary.gsub(/^/, "  "), nil].join("\n\n")
    20:       end
    21:     end.join
    22:     sections = sections.force_encoding('UTF-8').encode('UTF-16', :invalid => :replace).encode('UTF-8') if sections.respond_to?(:force_encoding)
    23: %>
    24: 
    25: <%= raw sections %>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the sense of this conerting to utf-16 and back is?^^

Comment: Good question, it's not any part of "my" code that is doing this. In the end, this is simply a symptom of another problem, namely that if you reference JS files in a view template and they have not been through the asset pipeline you get this error. Very non-intuitive I might add...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some fiddling, I traced the problem to included javascrips in my view, based on conditionals, which had to manually be listed in rails configuration in order to be put through the asset pipeline.

The relevant info from Rails Guides is:

> If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript
>   files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:
>
> config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']

in `production.rb`

```
# Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
# config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent my 4 hours trying to debug this exact same error message.

Are you using the workless gem ?

https://github.com/lostboy/workless

or any other kind of DelayedJob::Scaler?

Removing this gem fixed everything!

Comment: Actually I'm not, but I think I know why it happened, and that is that some assets that I include in the application did not go through the assets pipeline and that somehow caused this error... see if there are assets that you include conditionally in some views and didn't explicitly add to the assets pipeline.